# Can't access Dockerized app running on EC2 from outside

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, connectivity

I have a docker image running on EC2 but can't access the app from outside. I have allowed for all traffic for both inbound and outbound on the security group of the EC2 instance.

I run my docker with this command

`docker run -d -p 8000:80 <NAME OF IMAGE>`

Attached is EC2 instance's security rules.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with docker or EC2 instance rules.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Added 8000 to the security rule and still no luck.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the instances running on public subnets? Try tu ssh and curl or tell net to localhost to verify if its working on local

Answer (score 5):

You are mapping machine's port `8000` to docker container's port `80`. You should allow Port 8000 in security group inbound rule so that traffic can hit your machine.

As `8000` is mapped inside container's port `80`, traffic will redirect to port `80` and you will be able to see the container's content.

In case you want to double check then go to EC2 and run `ps -ef | grep 8000`, it will give you Port `8000` as running.

Comment: Thanks @Pacifist_AWS. I added the rule but still can't access. I'm getting ```refused to connect```

Comment: Did you check the port 8000 ? Is it running on EC2 machine?

Comment: Attached an image bro.

Comment: I would suggest you check NACL in that case. Check for the Inbound and Outbound rules there.

Comment: @bamerf I just replicated your scenario and mine is working fine. I have one EC2 running in the public subnet. Created Docker container on port mapped as 8000:80. Security group inbound rule allows 8000 and NACL allow all traffic. As pointed out by adiii, check if your EC2 is running in the public subnet.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. The issue was a docker run issue. changed it to `docker run -d -p 8000:8000 <NAME OF IMAGE>` and it works.